# Recursive to Iterative method for Binary Search Tree

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working on an assignment to get the height of the BST using an iterative method from an recursive method. Below will be the provided recursive code and my code. It is returning one greater than the actual height. For example, the height is suppose to be 4, but it returns 5.

```
//Provided code 
public  int getHeight() {
    return getHeight(root);
}

private int getHeight(Node node) {
    if (node==null) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        int leftHeight = getHeight(node.left);
        int rightHeight = getHeight(node.right);
        return Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
    }
}

//my code
public int getHeightI() {
    return getHeightI(root);
}

private int getHeightI(Node node) {
    Node curr = node;
    int leftHeight = 0;
    int rightHeight = 0;
    if (curr!=null) {
        while (curr.left!=null) {
            leftHeight++; 
            curr = curr.left;
        } 
        while (curr.right!=null) {
            rightHeight++; 
            curr = curr.right; 
        }
    }   
    return Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight)+1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding max depth of binary tree without recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886297/finding-max-depth-of-binary-tree-without-recursion)

Comment: The reason your current code is off by `1` is because you are adding `1` to the return statement.  But your algorithm itself is also wrong.  Please see the code in the link above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the link. It's full of useful stack implementations of finding the depth. However, I was looking for a way to implement it without using stacks. And yes, if I delete the +1 for the return statement it works, but I know that is not the correct way to fix this method.

Comment: You are going to need to use some sort of stack-esque data structure if you want to do this iteratively.  Actually, when you solve it recursively, you are _still_ using a stack: the function call stack.  Really, if you examine the machine code from both methods, they should look very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Code is returning one more than actual height of Tree. I suggest you to use this code

```
int height(tree* root)
{
if(!root)
{ return -1;
}
else{
return __max(root->left,root->right);
}
```

Hope you understand your mistake.